# How is the shape of the anchor boxes predefined in YOLO algorithm?

Tags: object-detection, yolo

I am not sure if I really understand how anchor boxes are defined. As far as I understand, in YOLO algorithm you define a set of "good" shapes (anchor boxes) that may contain the object you are trying to detect for each cell.

However, I don't really understand how do you predefine the shape of these anchor boxes. As far as I have seen, there are examples in which the algorithm outputs b<sub>x</sub>, b<sub>y</sub>, b<sub>h</sub> and b<sub>w</sub> values for each anchor box. Are you actually giving "freedom" to the algorithm to define these four values, or somehow is it being defined a fixed ratio between b<sub>h</sub> and b<sub>w</sub> for each of the anchor boxes? And how is this ratio defined in the output?